# How to put each data frame to each corresponding sub-list in a list

Tags: r, list

I'm building a R function to perform Spearman's rank correlation analysis of the clinical traits of interest with individual genes of interest across all the patients. I successfully created a function, which is called 'computeC', to do this task. You can try here:

1. the dummy data:

a, clinical data

```
df=structure(list(lymph = c(1L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 0L), npi = c(4.036, 
6.032, 6.03, 5.042, 3.046), stage = c(2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), row.names = c("MB-0362", 
"MB-0346", "MB-0386", "MB-0574", "MB-0503"), class = "data.frame")
```

NOTE: the number of clinical features of interest (columns) is unlimited and unfixed, depending on users' want. In this case, I choose three clinical traits: 'lymph', 'stage' and 'npi' as examples

b, the expression levels of those individual genes across all patients:

```
df1=structure(list(NCOR1 = c(0.6488, 0.3312, -0.3336, 0.2663, -1.3986
), ZFP36L1 = c(-1.4278, -1.9684, -1.4047, -1.1984, 0.397), SMAD4 = c(-0.5692, 
-2.5897, -1.4175, -2.2613, 0.6804), CDKN1B = c(-0.9829, -1.7246, 
-1.1409, -1.5033, -0.8475), CDH1 = c(-0.1387, 1.5924, -0.7637, 
1.2737, 0.5298), PIK3R1 = c(0.2649, -0.2267, -0.6875, -0.8364, 
1.3622), BRCA2 = c(0.6442, 1.2209, -0.6712, -1.0785, -0.296), 
    KMT2C = c(-0.8759, -0.327, -0.0154, -0.7076, -0.0817), KRAS = c(0.5975, 
    -0.0729, 0.0069, -1.3664, -0.9904), MUC16 = c(0.4375, -0.7318, 
    -0.5569, -0.8224, -0.3882)), row.names = c("MB-0362", "MB-0346", 
"MB-0386", "MB-0574", "MB-0503"), class = "data.frame")
```

2. This is code to build 'computeC':

> computeC = function(data,var,x)   {
>
> computeQ <- function(x){(x$P.value*nrow(x))/(x$rank)}
>
> ```
> #missing input
> if(missing(data)){
>   stop("Error: omics input is missing \n")
> }
>
> if(missing(var)){
>   stop("Error: clinical data is missing \n")
> }
>
> if(missing(x)){
>   stop("Error: clinical feature column in clinical data is missing \n")
> }
>
> #implementation
> cc1 <- data.frame(name=paste("Site", 1:ncol(data)),Estimate=NA ,P.value=NA)
> estimates = numeric(ncol(data))
> pvalues = numeric(ncol(data))
> for (i in c(1:ncol(data))) {
>   cc=cor.test(data[,i],var[,x],
>               method = "spearman")
>   cc1$Estimate[i]=cc$estimate
>   cc1$P.value[i]=cc$p.value
>   rownames(cc1) = colnames(data)[1:ncol(data)]
> }
> cc1 = cc1[,-1]
> order.pvalue = order(cc1$P.value)
> cc1 = cc1[order.pvalue,] #order rows following p-value
> cc1$rank = rank(cc1$P.value) #re-order
> cc1$Q.value = computeQ(cc1) #compute Q-value
> cc1 = cc1 %>% subset(P.value <= 0.05) #only retain Genes with P <=0.05
> cc1 = cc1 %>% subset(Q.value <= 0.05) #only retain Genes with Q <=0.05
> cc1 = dplyr::select(cc1, -rank)
> return(cc1)}
> ```

You can try running this function individually as follows. Due to a small size of dummy data, you can not see the exact results, I post results as figures to easily imagine how the result looks like:

```
library(dplyr)
computeC(df1,df,"lymph")
```

[image: figure1]

```
computeC(df1,df,"stage")
```

[image: figure 2]

```
computeC(df1,df,"npi")
```

[image: Figure 3]

Now I want to implement computeC automatically and continuously with each clinical features and simultaneously put these results to corresponding sub-lists in a list. This is what I try:

```
listCC=list();
for (i in length(names(df))){
    listCC[[i]] = computeC(df1,df, names(df)[i]}
```

But it did not work as expected. Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function returns an empty dataframe with some warnings for me for the data you have shared but perhaps, you can use `lapply` :

```
lapply(names(df), computeC, data = df1, var = df)
```

Comment: Like I said, due to a small number of samples size in dummy data, function will return wrong answers!
Btw, Your solution is so simple but efficient! Thanks bunch!

Comment: @HuyNguyen you are welcome. BTW you don't need `for` loop and `lapply`, you can use any one of them.